# Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 2 but received 0

Tags: javascript, mysql, banco-de-dados, discord

Após muito tempo em idle, aparece essa mensagem no terminal, e a aplicação para, quando recebe novos comandos da o erro "`Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state` e preciso reiniciar, estou começando agora com mysql e não achei muita informação sobe esse Warning

`Warning: got packets out of order. Expected 2 but received 0`

**db.js**

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
let connection;

module.exports = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_host,
    user: process.env.DB_user,
    password: process.env.DB_password,
    database: process.env.DB_database
})
```

**Exemplo de qury que uso**

```
const [query]  = await connection.query(
    `SELECT * FROM guildconfigurable WHERE guildId = '${guildid}'`
)
```

Comment: Pelo que li pode ser mesmo um bug dessa lib ou conflito com alguma configuração inesperada, ao invés createConnection use createPool, pelo que li nesse caso não ocorre o problema

Comment: vou testar, como o problema acontece depois de várias horas sem interação, assim que descobrir volto para dar o feedback, obrigado desde já.